# Largest gap between two consecutive space launches?

Tags: launch, history

What was the largest period without space launches after say 1970?
I had to chose a random year because I guess in the first years of the Space Age the gaps were the largest anyway.

Related questions:

- [What was the most busy week in space launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45696/what-was-the-most-busy-week-in-space-launches)
- [Most busy times in US space launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45715/most-busy-times-in-us-space-launches)
- [What is the longest period of consecutive space launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45725/what-is-the-longest-period-of-consecutive-space-launches)

Comment: Worldwide, or are you looking for a specific country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [JSR launch report data](https://planet4589.org/space/log/launch.html), there have been five gaps of 30+ days since 1961. Note that these are all calculated on the basis of calendar days in UTC - depending on exactly where and when they were launched, the "local" dates might be ± a day either way.

- 35 days, 1961-12-22 to 1962-01-26 (plus [two failed launches](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_chr/lau1962.htm))
- 30 days, 1963-02-19 to 1963-03-21 (plus [two failed launches](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_chr/lau1963.htm))
- 32 days, 1993-02-21 to 1993-03-25
- 32 days, 2001-10-25 to 2001-11-26
- 35 days, 2005-11-16 to 2005-12-21

Prior to December 1961, gaps were a lot longer - there were several periods of two or three months, and one of almost four months (116 days) in mid-1959.

This data covers all successful or partially successful launches but does not include failed launches - if you count those, the time between launch attempts is shorter. On close examination, the 1960s periods had a couple of those, which I've flagged up.

Comment: I think it would be also interesting to find the largest gap between US launches. I am not allowed to ask questions, if you ask that question and answer it then I will put a bounty of 100 points for it and award it to you