# Largest number of rockets launched into space from a given launch site in a 24 hour period?

Tags: launch, launch-site, record, sounding-rocket

**Question:** What is the largest number of rockets launched into space from a given launch site in a 24 hour period? Where, when, why?

"into space" means $\ge$ 100 km, but pretty close to 100 km would still count. However a hobby rocket *launch-a-thon* topping out at a kilometer or two wouldn't.

Thus answers to [Most busy times in US space launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45715/12102) are not likely to cover this.

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45696/195

Comment: Near dupe: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/45719/195

Comment: @RussellBorogove at first it looks like it but those are all orbital launches. There may turn out to be a much more interesting event involving sounding rockets with a number much larger than single digits. So I've added a link to that question back in the post. *Thanks!*

Comment: Do you have a particular event in mind?

Comment: @RussellBorogove I'd read about one, but I can't track it down now. It seemed like a "launch-a-thon" for scientists.

Comment: Are you thinking of [RockOn](https://www.nasa.gov/wallops/2021/feature/student-experiments-to-blast-off-from-nasa-wallops) ? I think that's multiple payloads on a single sounding rocket.

Comment: (Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53732/195)

Comment: No, separate rockets. It was for science somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working my way through the past missions listed by the NASA Sounding Rockets Program Office, which has a few multiple launches, mostly doubles.

Standouts include:

- A [launch of 5 sounding rockets from Wallops on 27 March 2012 for the UE Larsen/Clemson University
  Anomalous TRansport EXperiment (ATREX)](https://sites.wff.nasa.gov/code810/news/story128.html). Per NASA, [altitude was 50-90 miles](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/sunearth/missions/atrex-nightlight.html). There's also a [Wikipedia article on the experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_Transport_Rocket_Experiment).
- A triple launch to about 53 miles altitude: [the SuperSoaker experiment (NASA)](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2021/nasa-mission-seeks-to-understand-bright-night-shining-clouds-by-creating-one). [Here's a ScienceDaily article](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2021/03/210301091156.htm) on it.

Comment: I'll keep thinking about this also, trying to remember what I'd read or more importantly where I'd read it.

Comment: Ah, got it! Now that you mention Wallops; searching this site for [wallops+sounding+rockets](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=wallops+sounding+rockets) I found an answer that has a big number. It will need a bit more research to source it properly but I think it's what's needed.

Comment: Wow. That collection of rockets would pack quite a....

Comment: Would you like to add that to your answer? It seems that if six or more reached space then it beats ATREX.